# esp8266 esp-01 crashing, restarting over and over

Tags: esp8266

I flashed my ESP-01 with the [nodemcu firmware 512k version](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware), and everything was working fine.  I testing some lua scripting on init.lua and it was working.  Then, after writing a bunch of code and uploading, the module restarted.  And it restarted.  And it's still restarting, over and over again, and prints to serial

```
CÀbc0°ýbcü¨HøNodeMcu 0.9.4 build 20141230  powered by Lua 5.1.4
ö,3bþÈH
```

It was always printing the garbage in there before, so I'm not worried about that.  However, I can't send anything to the device--I can't send serial commands, or reflash the device.  I'm thinking I overloaded the memory or something.  Anyone have any ideas for recovering this brick?

Comment: This is really not the right website for this question.  If you were running a port of the Arduino framework to the ESP8266, that might barely be a fit (though still much better supported on an ESP8266 site), but here your question concerns neither Arduino-type hardware nor software.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was pulling up on the GPIO0 pin, instead of down.  Ensure you have the correct pin-out when flashing.

ESP-01 VCC - 3.3v Serial Adapter
ESP-01 GND - Ground or Minus Serial Adapter
ESP-01 RX - Connect to TX on Serial Adapter
ESP-01 TX - Connect to RX on Serial Adapter
ESP-01 CH_PD - 3.3v Serial Adapter
ESP-01 GPIO0 - Pull low by connecting to ground / minus

There also seems to be a problem with NodeMCU not clearing variables in the Ram, so Ram fills up as you run, and this causes the module to crash upon restarting, over and over.  That is also what was happening.  There is some problem with wifi.sta.getap() that exacerbates this.